# Creating AVRO generic record schema from postgres JSON field

Tags: python, google-bigquery, avro

I'm doing a dump from my PostgreSQL to GCP BigQuery. Our Postgres JSON fields have no schema defined, so some lines have different keys. So far, I just loaded JSON data as String in BQ, but the ideia is to load JSON fields as RECORD in BQ to avoid CASTing, like JSON_EXTRACT.

Let's create an example:

```
from fastavro import writer, parse_schema

table = "example"

schema = {
        'doc': f'Extraction of {table}',
        'name': f'{table}',
        'namespace': f'{table}',
        'type': 'record',
        'fields': [
            {'name': 'info',
             'type': {'type': 'record',
                      'name': 'info',
                      'fields': [{"name": "key_1",
                                  "type": ["null", "int"]},
                                {"name": "key_2",
                                 "type": ["null", "string"]}
                                 ]
                      }
             }
        ]
    }

parsed_schema = parse_schema(schema)
```

Here, we have a schema that is able to create AVRO using this fields:

```
records =  [{u'info': {u"key_1": 3, u"key_2": u"AVRO_TEST"}}]

with open(f'{table}.avro', 'wb') as out:
    writer(out, parsed_schema, records)
```

This one works pretty well.

But, postgres JSON field (info) has different keys, so my 'real' data is something like this:

```
records = [{u'info': {u"key_1": 3, u"key_2": u"AVRO_TEST"}},
           {u'info': {u"key_3": u"info"}},
           {u'info': {}}, # actual is a empty json (or dict)
           {u'info': None}] # NULL, considering database
```

I tried Spark to generate AVRO and PARQUET, but both of them are extracting and saving the JSON field as STRING in BQ.
We need a structure like the one below, even that we have more 'columns' (one for each new key).
[image: BQ Example]

I've been stuck on this by a week now, trying different ways from SPARK to manual file generation. I'm new in this kind of 'Big Data' problem and I'm feeling like there is no much options left, unless CASTint JSON_EXTRACT BQ function when reading the database.

Anyone can help me on how I can create an 'generic' schema for AVRO/PARQUET/ORC, or even point me to another direction to solve this?

Really appreciate our help. Thanks in advance :)